# not supported by the language

Tags: c#, c++, clr

I code regularly in C++, and for the specific project I'm working on right now, I'm writing a C++ lib whose methods are to be used in a C# lib, whose methods are to be used in a C# app.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10.

I created a solution with 3 projects :

1. A C++/CLI dynamic lib (`New Project => Visual C++ => CLR => Class Library`)
2. A C# lib (`New Project => Windows Classic Desktop => Class Library (.NET Framework)`)
3. And a C# app (`New Project => Windows Classic Desktop => Console App (.NET Framework)`)

For now, I'm just trying to make the 3 projects communicate together, and I seem to have problems between the C++ lib and the C# lib.

The code in my C++ lib is the following ;

**cppLib.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using std::string;

using namespace System;

namespace cppLib {
    public ref class cppClass
    {
    public:
        static string test();
        static double add(double arg1, double arg2);
    };
}
```

**cppLib.cpp**

```
#include "cppLib.h"

namespace cppLib {
    string cppClass::test() {
        return "Hello World from C++ lib.";
    }

    double cppClass::add(double arg1, double arg2) {
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}
```

The code in my C# lib is the following :

**Wrapper.cs**

```
using cppLib;

namespace CsWrapper
{
    public class Wrapper
    {
        //static public string TestCppLib()
        //{
        //    return cppClass.test();
        //}

        static public double Add(double arg1, double arg2)
        {
            return cppClass.add(arg1, arg2);
        }

        public string WrapperTest()
        {
            return "Hello World from C# lib.";
        }
    }
}
```

As is, this code builds without errors nor warnings. So I can call my `static double add(double arg1, double arg2);` method from my C++ lib in my C# lib method `static public double Add(double arg1, double arg2)`, BUT if I try to uncomment the following code in **Wrapper.cs** :

```
        //static public string TestCppLib()
        //{
        //    return cppClass.test();
        //}
```

I get the `'cppClass.test(?)' is not supported by the language` error message :

```
Severity    Code        Description                                             Project     File                                        Suppression State
Error       CS0570      'cppClass.test(?)' is not supported by the language     CsWrapper   D:\documents\...\CsWrapper\Wrapper.cs       Active
```

What does it mean? How can I call one method from my C++ lib in my C# lib without problem, but the other I can't? My `public string WrapperTest()` method returns a string all right that I can use in my C# app (it works, I can display it), so why can't I call that specific C++ method in my C# lib? It's also really my first time coding in C#.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the cause of the error, but `std::string` != `System.String`

Comment: I'm with @Neijwiert. I'm pretty sure that is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Also a sidenote: why are you creating a wrapper class for a C++/CLI library? The whole point of C++/CLI is that you can directly interface to and from it in a managed .Net app.

Comment: You cannot return a native C++ template type and expect C# code to know how to use it.  Only a C++ compiler can ever do that, and only the exact same compiler version using the exact same compile options.  Change the return type to `String^`.

Comment: @Neijwiert The wrapper class existence is not up to me, it's a requisite of the project :/

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you so much! It works! I have no idea what `String^` is or why or how, but it works! 

If someone can post an answer with an explanation to why it's `String^`, I'd would grateful, because now I know it works, but I don't know why. I'm currently looking it up myself, and if I understand before someone else answers, I'll put the answer myself so as to close the question.

Comment: It's the managed (.Net variant) of a string. std::string is an unmanaged type. Using `^` indicates that it is a ref class (managed) pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++/CLI, a string cannot be returned as a native C++ template type if the method is to be used by a C# app / lib, because the C# code won't know how to use it.

The managed (.Net variant) of the type has to be used; for a C++ `string`, it's a `String^`. The  `^` indicates that it is a ref class (managed) pointer.

The code becomes :

**cppLib.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

using std::string;

using namespace System;

namespace cppLib {
    public ref class cppClass
    {
    public:
        static String^ test();
        static double add(double arg1, double arg2);
    };
}
```

**cppLib.cpp**

```
#include "cppLib.h"

namespace cppLib {
    String^ cppClass::test() {
        return "Hello World from C++ lib.";
    }

    double cppClass::add(double arg1, double arg2) {
        return arg1 + arg2;
    }
}
```

The rest stays the same.